# How to get the height of a textView

Tags: objective-c

Hi all i have used autoresizemask for textview like this :                textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
so the textView size changed depending on the size of text but is it possible to get the size of a textview after resizing the height. bcz i tried to get but it is giving the same size.

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

is used when your view is rotated from portrait to landscape and vice versa. It doesn't changes the height in the same orientation.

Comment: @Thank you Inder Kumar Rathore. But i got change in textview view before and after applying the autoresize.

Comment: it's because initially should auto rotate is called.

Comment: @Sandy ... again `autoresizingMask` is not made for changing the size according to the text in it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float f = yourTextView.bounds.size.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Inder Kumar Rathore explained, setting `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` does **not** make your text view automatically change its size when its content changes.

There is no flag you can set to make the text view automatically change its size based on its content.

`UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, and `UIScrollView` has a `contentSize` property.  So if you want to know the size of the text view's content, you can just ask it:

```
CGSize size = self.textView.contentSize;
```

If you want to make the text view resize itself to the height of its content, you can tell it to do that:

```
[self.textView sizeToFit];
```

The text view never calls `sizeToFit` automatically.  You have to do it explicitly.